# For a cont. map $A:\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ its kernel $K$ is a Schwartz function iff $A:\mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{S}$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, schwartz-space

Let $A:\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a continuous map and denote by $K \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ its Schwartz kernel. Show that $K \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2n)$ if and only if $A$ maps $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

This is an exercise in Peter Hintz' lecture notes on microlocal analysis which can be found at [https://people.math.ethz.ch/~hintzp/notes/micro.pdf](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Ehintzp/notes/micro.pdf). I am using them for exam preparation.

My ideas:\

$\Rightarrow$: Assume that $K \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})$. Then:
\begin{equation}
\langle K, v \otimes u \rangle =
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}} K(x,y)v(x)u(y) dy  = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\underbrace{(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}K(x,y)u(y)dy)}_{Au(x)}v(x) dx
\end{equation}

and now we can argue that for multiindices \begin{equation}
\alpha, \beta: \text{sup}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}|x^{\alpha}D^{\beta} Au(x)|
\end{equation}

can be written as:
\begin{equation}
\text{sup}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}|x^{\alpha}D^{\beta} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}K(x,y)u(y)dy| < \infty
\end{equation}

where in the last bound, we used that $K$ is a Schwartz-function in $x$, via dominated convergence.

Idea for the other direction:\

Maybe we can write $K(x,y) = \langle A \delta_y, \delta_x \rangle$

Comment: Are you sure about the other direction? $(Au)(v):= \int uv$ (i.e. $A$ is the "identity map") so that $K(x,y)=\delta(x-y)$, which is not a Schwarz function.

Comment: @s.harp Yes, but the identity is not a well-defined map from $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Comment: @PaulJoh wdym the identity is not well defined? It seems to me it is perfectly well defined (and Hintz's notes present a definition at page 6, equation 2.10).